# Visual Studio 2019 installation freezes

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 freezes on install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Aspnet45.Feature and I could not do anything.

[image]

I found something like killing `DISM.exe` process from task manager, but I could not find anything like that. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is not really an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. You would be better off asking on the [appropriate forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com), or perhaps [checking for an answer here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8&ftype=problem&preview2=true&q=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Aspnet45.Feature) where it seems a lot of other people have had this problem. And of course - as always - look at the installation logs for a specific error.

Comment: @godot, you can try to restart your computer or update your system version to the latest. Also, I find a similar link about your question, you can have a look: [Installation of Visual Studio 2017 stuck at 99%](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/installation-of-visual-studio-2017-stuck-at-99-1/998770).